# Removing NSManagedObject from NSOrderedSet in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableViewController` that properly displays an `NSOrderedSet` associated with an `NSManagedObject`. On this `UITableView`, I've configured a button that enables editing and I'm able to re-order the items in the `NSOrderedSet` without a problem. Nothing happens when I try to delete--perhaps most aggravatingly, it doesn't crash.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to configure it to delete cells. What am I missing?

My `viewDidLoad` initially loads `self.isEditing = NO`.

I have a `UIButton` configured that toggles `self.isEditing` between `YES` & `NO`.

```
- (IBAction)toggleEditButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    // You need to do 2 things:
    // 1 - Edit
    if (self.isEditing == NO) {
        NSLog(@"isEditing is in edit mode");
        self.editButton.title = @"Done";
        self.isEditing = YES;
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    } else {
        // 2 - Save
        NSLog(@"isEditing is in save mode");
        self.editButton.title = @"Edit";
        self.isEditing = NO;
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When `self.isEditing` is set to `YES`, I am able to move items around in my `NSOrderedSet` and save the re-ordered `NSOrderedSet`.

Here's my `commitEditingStyle`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        //
        [self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet = self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy;
        [tableView reloadData];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
```

Thank you for reading. I welcome your input.

**Update**
I tried a couple of solutions below and the behavior continues to be the same on this `UITableViewController`--reorder controls show up, but no delete and swiping to delete when in editing mode does nothing.

I have a `customCell` configured. Could layout constraints be covering something up?

**Update 2**
In response to Paulw11's Q have I implemented `canEditRowAtIndexPath` and `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`, yes. Here they are:

**`editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

This appears to be the majority of my problem. I originally had it set to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`. I never "bumped into" a problem with I reordering working, so I didn't think to look there. I updated it as follows.

**`canEditRowAtIndexPath`**

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Originally, code was:
// return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone
    if (self.isEditing == YES) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Now I get this error:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of
 rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after 
the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section 
before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from 
that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved 
into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

I think I can figure it out from here. I'll update to final solution in the morning--going to hang up my spurs for the evening upon discovering this silly mistake and pick up in the morning :)

Comment: If you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` then you don't need to call `reloadData`. Have you set a breakpoint to confirm that this method actually executes?

Comment: Thank you. At your suggestion, I threw a breakpoint in and nothing happens when I'm in editing mode (aside form re-order controls appearing).

Comment: Have you implemented `canEditRowAtIndexPath` or `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`?  If so, please show these methods

Comment: Ugh! I think `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` was the majority of my problem. I updated the post. I think I can figure the rest out, as I've encountered the invalid # of rows in section before. I'll futz around w/ it in the morning and post what gets me squared away. Thank you for your assistance on this.

Comment: I added `[self.tableview beginUpdates]` & `[self.tableView endUpdates]` and that solved the inconsistency problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out most of my problem I have lived in `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`. My original method, which I didn't touch when I was only reordering the `tableView`, looked like this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Upon paul11's query what it looked like in my implementation, I updated to this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.isEditing == YES) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I updated `commitEditingStyle` at **pbasdf**'s suggestion as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete && self.routineToEdit.stretches.count > 2) {
        // this needs to be added to keep an consistency error from being thrown
        // you'll also need to end updates when it's done deleting
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        // pbasdf suggested this for handling the NSOrderedSet
        NSMutableOrderedSet *tempSet = self.myNSManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy;
        [tempSet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.myNSManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet = tempSet;
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        // and you need to save the context so the deletion persists
        [self saveContext];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Thank you to all for your input!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in these lines:

```
[self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet = self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy;
```

The first line creates a mutable copy of your ordered set, then removes one object.
The second line creates *another* mutable copy of the original set.

Try assigning to a temporary variable:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *tempSet = self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet.mutableCopy;
[tempSet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.myManagedObject.myNSOrderedSet = tempSet;
```

Comment: Thx! I like what you did w/ the `tempSet`, but nothing happens on the delete front when I am in Edit mode--only the re-order controls show up. Nothing happens when I try to swipe and no delete button appears.

Answer (score 1):

is `myNSOrderedSet` a Core Data relationship attribute? If so, you should be using

```
[[mymanagedObject mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"myNSOrderedSet"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

and that's it; you don't need to assign it back to `myNSOrderedSet`.

(Note that depending on your table view's data source, you may need to call `save` on the object's `NSManagedObjectContext`)

Comment: Thanks! I tried your idea and it doesn't crash, but I only get re-order controls to show up. Nothing for deleting.